# get maximum from a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get or fetch maximum date from a table grouped by party_id.

To do this I tried:

```
$check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select max(fixed_date) as f from case_proceeding group by party_id where party_id='$row[party_id]'"));
```

After that, I want to print that maximum date like this:

```
echo $check['f'];
```

but it does not work. I think there is a mistake in the mysql_query.

Comment: group by goes after where. instead of putting it on on one line, breaking it down so you can use error checking is advised

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try, `GROUP BY` (*which should come after `WHERE` clause*) isn't needed here since you already filtered from `WHERE`

```
$check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select max(fixed_date) as f from case_proceeding where party_id='$row[$party_id]'"));
```

but your quesry is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, please read the article below to protect against it

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

GROUP BY clause is not required here

```
select max(fixed_date) as f 
from   case_proceeding 
where  party_id='$row[party_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
select max(DATE(fixed_date)) as f from case_proceeding where party_id=? group by party_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select max(fixed_date) as f from case_proceeding where party_id='$row[party_id]' "));
```

**Note** :mysql_* function are deprecated so try pdo or mysqli